# Maven plugins; using output of one as input for another

Tags: java, maven

My problem is that I have written a maven plugin to deploy the artifact to a user specified location. I'm now trying to write another maven plugin to use this deployed artifact, change some things and zip it again. 
I want to write the second plugin such that i use the first plugin to get the information for where it was deployed. 
I don't know how to access this information from the first plugin.

Comment: In which kind is your plugin special in comparsion to maven-deploy-plugin etc. And what's the reason to write a maven-plugin for that purpose? And why are you reinventing the wheel, cause this kind of plugins like maven-assembly-plugin already exist?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with @Barend that if you can afford to make changes before deploy, that could be best strategy.

If you cannot do that, you can follow strategy of a plugin like Maven Release plugin. Maven release plugin runs in two phases where second run needs output of the first run. They manage it by keeping temporary properties file in the project directory which carry the information like tag name, SNAPSHOT version name etc.

You could use the same approach with plugin. Just remember that your plugin will be sort of transactional, where it expects the other goal to have run before it can do its work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the easiest workaround is to reverse the order in which the plugins run.

Have Plugin B run first, using the known location under `target/` to modify the artifact and then run Plugin A, deploying the modified artifact to the configured location.

If that's no option, I suggest you simply duplicate the configuration value (so that both plugins are told about the new location in their `<configuration>` element). This keeps both plugins independent, which is what Maven assumes them to be.

A last option is to make make Plugin B parse the entire POM and extract the information from Plugin A's `<configuration>` element, but I really can't recommend this. If you go this way the two plugins are so closely intertwined that they're really just one plugin. This is poor design, violates the principle of least surprise and might cause nasty configuration problems down the line.